# Moving form $_FILES to $_GET

Tags: php

I have one old function that I need to edit

```
doSome($_FILES['image']);
```

My question is how can I use the same function in order to get a file from GET instead of uploading it?

If I change to

```
doSome($_GET['image']);
```

It doesn't seem to work...

Comment: It sounds like you are confused. Have you set the form's enctype to 'multipart/form-data' ?

Comment: Not possible, why would you want to? `$_FILES` is not going anywhere to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files uploaded through a form will always end up in PHP's `$_FILES` superglobal. You can't change that.

You could if you modified PHP's source I suppose.

---

If you're talking about simply passing a filename to the `doSome()` function, you could check if the function's argument is an array or not and handle it accordingly.

> (Array = from $_FILES, String = NOT from $_FILES)

Answer (score 1):

The faking-it option would be:

```
doSome( array("tmp_name" => "data:n/a,".$_GET["image"]) );
```

But in practice you wouldn't want that or should at least create a temporary file and mimick the $_FILES subarray more completely.

And rewriting your old function to accept just the filename or string content would be wiser.